# Update partial view in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm working on a new project with asp.net MVC5. In this project, I have unlimited categories with unlimited subcategories.

I want to convert my categories + categories children to menus. I know that I can create these menus on my base controller but I don't like to render categories always.

I decided to create a partial view like _MenuPartial.cshtml and generate menus when the user creates a new category or update and for the latest step, I render this partial view in my layout.

I couldn't find any resource for this situation.

Can I convert a string to partial view in controller? Or do I have to create a txt file and save my menu there and convert it to HTML each time?

Comment: Step 1) Write the HTML for the menu in your partial view and include that in other views as needed.

Comment: @Shyju I know how can I use partial views but how can I generate html in partial view in controller?

Comment: How do you determine if you want the menus or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this situation, I suggest you to create an action for rendering the menu. Then you can use it every where that you want to be rendered. For example in your `Home.cshml`

Your action controller should be like this:

```
public PartialViewResult MainMenu()
{
   List<YourApp.Models.Menu> menuItems = new List<YourApp.Models.Menu>();

   /* Add your menus item here */

   menuItems.Add(
        new YourApp.Models.Menu() {
            Title = "Level 1",
            SubItems = new List<YourApp.Models.Menu>() {
                new YourApp.Models.Menu() {
                    Title = "Level 2",
                    SubItems = new List<YourApp.Models.Menu>() {
                        new YourApp.Models.Menu() {
                            Title = "Level 3",
                            Url = Url.Action("SampleAction", "SampleController")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   );
   return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/MainMenu", menuItems);
}
```

And here is an example of `MainMenu.cshtml` view for making a menu using bootstrap framework:

```
@model YourApp.Models.Menu;

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-weight:bold;">
        @* Create a for loop on first level of menu model *@
        @foreach(var firstLevel in Model){
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@(firstLevel.Title)
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    @* Iterate on children of first level items *@
                    @foreach(var secondLevel in firstLevel.SubItems){
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@(secondLevel.Title)
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                @foreach(var thirdLevel in secondLevel.SubItems){
                                    <li><a href="@(thirdLevel.Url)">@(thirdLevel.Title)</a></li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can call this code and render `MainMenu.cshtml` in your view (e.g. `Home.cshtml` or `Index.cshtml`):

`@Html.Action("MainMenu", "Home")`